# How can I return HttpResponse after calling a class which implements Queueable

Tags: apex, httpcalloutmock

As described in the title, I have a class which implements the Queueable interface, for each item it sends an http request and I would like to get the response back and use it.

My problem is that I must implement the method:

```
void System.Queueable.execute(System.QueueableContext)
```

I was hoping to achieve something similar to:

```
HttpResponse System.Queueable.execute(System.QueueableContext)
```

How can it be done?

Apex Code:

```
public class QueueableSlackCall implements System.Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts {

    private final String url;
    private final String method;
    private final String body;

    public QueueableSlackCall(String url, String method, String body) {
        this.url = url;
        this.method = method;
        this.body = body;
    }

    public void execute(System.QueueableContext ctx) {

            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            req.setMethod(method);
            req.setBody(body);
            Http http = new Http();
            HttpResponse res;
            req.setEndpoint(url);
            res = http.send(req);
            System.debug('Slack HTTP Response: '+res);

    }
}
```

The reason I want to return 'res' is to be able to test it in my unit test:

```
@isTest
private class SlackTest {
     @isTest static void testCallout() {
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockHttpResponseGenerator());
        HttpResponse res = QueueableSlackCall.execute();
        System.assertEquals(200, res.getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the request is executed asynchronously, i.e. an arbitrary time in the future, the response is not available to the code that makes the original `Queueable.execute` request. So you have to re-think your logic and process the response *inside* the `public void execute(System.QueueableContext ctx)` method e.g. store the response or perform whatever other database modification is appropriate.

If you want to see the result of the call in the user interface, you will have to set something up that polls to check for the result and then displays it when it is available - a chunk of extra work.

On the testing, you can include asserts in your `MockHttpResponseGenerator` class i.e. assert that it is called. s in a test it is generating the response, there isn't much point in directly asserting about that. And if you include a `Test.stopTest()` call in your test, after that call you can assert about any database changes made because it ensures any asynchronous calls are completed.

Comment: thanks, in regards to the last paragraph, it only posts a message to Slack, it does not change the sf database so nothing to assert.

Comment: @Json Ok then just assert that the `HttpRequest` is of the right form in `MockHttpResponseGenerator`; you will still need to call `Test.stopTest()` in your test to ensure the asynchronous logic runs.